# How can mypy accept pydantic's constr() types?

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I have this code:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

DeptNumber = constr(min_length=6, max_length=6)

class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    dept: DeptNumber

ms = MyStuff(dept = "123456")
```

> deptnr.py:6: error: Variable "deptnr.DeptNumber" is not valid as a type
> deptnr.py:6: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases

The provided link doesn't seem to really address my problem (I'm not using `Type`).

This happens with or without this `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
plugins = pydantic.mypy

[pydantic-mypy]
init_typed = true
```

Initially I also had that error in a Pydantic `choice` as below, but I got around that by using Python's `Literal` instead.

```
DIR = choice(["North", "East", "South", "West"])
```

What do I need to change to make mypy happy with my Pydantic `constr`?

Comment: `DIR` isn't a type.  If `pydantic` doesn't have type stubs, you could either write type stubs yourself, or you could type it as `Any`.

Comment: Are you running the [mypy plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/mypy_plugin/)?

Comment: @SuperShoot Yes, it doesn't seem to make a difference, though.

Comment: take a look at [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to use `Field` from `Pydantic` :

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    dept: str = Field(..., min_length=6, max_length=6)
```

It seems working for me.

Comment: The `Field` function also allows a number of constraints to be added to the field https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customisation

Comment: This does *not* work with `strip_whitespace=True`.

Comment: The "constr" is the correct way. Field don't works as expected.

Comment: Specifically for `constr`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67871116/7955271) other answer appears to offer a more complete (if less "idiomatic") solution. Have tried with Pylance (but not mypy) and it works.

Answer (score 29):

This incompatibility with mypy has been discussed in this Github issue https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/156. Sadly, no concrete solution that uses `constr` *and* keeps mypy happy was found.

On Pydantic v1 <sup>note 1</sup>, instead of `constr`, you can subclass pydantic's `ConstrainedStr`, which offers the same configurations and options as `constr`, but without mypy complaining about type aliases.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConstrainedStr

class DeptNumber(ConstrainedStr):
    min_length = 6
    max_length = 6

class MyStuff(BaseModel):
    dept: DeptNumber

ms = MyStuff(dept='123456')
```

The `Constrained*` classes are briefly mentioned in the [Strict Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#strict-types) section of the docs. It is defined in [pydantic/types.py](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/v1.8.2/pydantic/types.py#L359) and as you can see is basically the same as `constr`:

```
class ConstrainedStr(str):
    strip_whitespace = False
    to_lower = False
    min_length: OptionalInt = None
    max_length: OptionalInt = None
    curtail_length: OptionalInt = None
    regex: Optional[Pattern[str]] = None
    strict = False

    ...
```

Validation works the same:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ms = MyStuff(dept='123456789')
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 406, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyStuff
dept
  ensure this value has at most 6 characters (type=value_error.any_str.max_length; limit_value=6)
```

---

<sup>note 1:

I haven't gotten a chance to work with Pydantic v2 yet, so I don't know if it still works on that version.

I can only guarantee that the answer works on v1.</sup>

Comment: Sadly this still seems to result in a general type issue with pylance. :/

Comment: @Monkeyphant That's unfortunate. I don't use Pylance, and mypy != pylance, and the original question was for mypy, no mention of pylance. You might want to ask a separate question for pylance.

Comment: mypy is still complaining ;`Argument "dept" to "MyStuff" has incompatible type "str"; expected "DeptNumber"  [arg-type]`. Do you a specific mypy configuration?

Comment: @guhur I don't have a copy of the env I used for this answer, so I don't remember. But I reproduced the issue from the same code from the question, and applied my answer, and it still works. Using Python 3.8/3.9/3.10, pydantic 1.10.2, mypy 0.990 (with all default configs). I simply ran `mypy test.py` where `test.py` contains the code from this answer. Tried with `mypy --strict` and still no errors. Also doesn't show any error when enabling mypy in VS Code.

Comment: On `pyproject.toml`, I had to use `init_typed=False` to make it work in the section `[too.pydantic-mypy]`.

Comment: @guhur Huh, thanks for the info. I'm using [setup.cfg to enable the pydantic.mypy plugin](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/mypy_plugin/#enabling-the-plugin), and all I have is `[mypy] > plugins = pydantic.mypy`

Comment: As of 5 Feb 2023, this solution [works for me](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/3912) with Pylance.

Comment: This is the nicest workaround I've found for this problem yet, it's quite clean: https://github.com/koxudaxi/datamodel-code-generator/issues/492#issue-965007077

Answer (score 7):

In Pydantic V2, you can use the `StringConstraints` type along with `Annotated`:

```py
from pydantic import stringConstraints
from typing import Annotated

DeptNumber = Annotated[
    str,
    StringConstraints(
        min_length=6,
        max_length=6,
    )
]
```

`Annotated` makes sure that `DeptNumber` is a `str` type, while adding some functionality on top of it.